# How do i make a SQLite3 database in python so that anyone can see its contents and access it from their computer?

Tags: python, sql, database

I need to find a way to make it so my sqlite3 database that i have created can be accessed by anyone. The users will have the program code but when i try to see its contents on a different device it shows it to be empty (as the database i have created is specific to the computer). Im using python to do this.

Comment: Do you have any server setup or is the database on a NAS or something like that?

Comment: @RobinWeiland The database is just setup using the mySql plugin in python and no external server setup or NAS

Comment: Then I guess it will always create a new database when you do `conn = sqlite3.connect('example.db') `  and the db does not already exist which it does not on a different machine

Comment: SQLite is a file-level (non-server) RDBMS. If all users connect to a shared drive, place database in a central location where all users can have read/write access.

Comment: I think I read that in the docs somewhere but couldn't find it right now so I tested it and indeed it does not care whether the db exists and just creates a new one without a warning

Comment: Or you could create your own server with `socket` but @Parfait 's approach is far more practical if all users are able to reach the drive